# Delete a Method in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a function with 2 methods

```
function foo(a::Integer) 42 end
function foo(a::String) 24 end

foo(2)
42

foo("a")
24
```

How can I delete just one of the two methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a type `Method`. Instances of that type refer to a specific method of a particular function.

```
particular_method = @which foo(2)
foo(a::Integer) in Main at /home/js/Documents/Julia/Matching/Query_Creation.jl:75

typeof(particular_method)
Method
```

And here's a way to delete the method using such an object:

```
Base.delete_method(particular_method)

foo(2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching foo(::Int64)
```

Comment: Note that this is a somewhat internal unofficially API. That said, it’s unlikely to go away.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a different way to do it?

Comment: No, that’s it, it’s just not an official API, although perhaps it should be made official.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your code in a file tracked by Revise, then deleting the method in the source will delete it in your running session. If I copy your two definitions to a file `/tmp/delmeth.jl`, then

```
julia> using Revise

julia> Revise.includet("/tmp/delmeth.jl")

julia> foo(2)
42

julia> foo("a")
24
```

Now, in your editor, delete the method for `foo(::String)`, save the file, and in the same session do this:

```
julia> foo(2)
42

julia> foo("a")
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching foo(::String)
Closest candidates are:
  foo(::Integer) at /tmp/delmeth.jl:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[6]:1
```

If you're developing anything "serious" & reusable, then you should generally create packages, in which case you don't need `includet` because Revise  automatically tracks packages that you've loaded with `using` or `import`. See the [Revise docs](https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/) for further details.